# Splitting html angular files

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I want to split my html file (angular based). however, I do not want to use ng-include as it loads it whether it is shown or not. I want to include it if the ng-if condition is true.

I have two paragraphs (can be restructured) and only ONE of the paragraphs is shown at a time (based on ng-if) if I use ng-include, I am reloading them and I do not want that.

Can you recommend me something better?

EDIT: I realized I got older version of Angular and cannot use ng-if and only ng-show.  What can I do?

Comment: Why can't you put the `ng-show` or `ng-if` directive right on the `<p>` elements that need to be conditionally shown/hidden?

Comment: I want to split my files. I do not want to work with the same html file (reason i wrote this question)

Comment: ng-include doesn't load the template if the ng-if expression is falsy. Test it with http://plnkr.co/edit/tzU8k5CQM3UDWx0IAXkF?p=preview: open the network tab of your browser dev tools, and you'll see that foo.html is only loaded once you click on the Load button

Comment: @kaveman after about 200 nested ng-if's it starts to get bad - you don't really want to have to stare at it for an hour to tell whats up :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a parameter on the scope:

```
$scope.partToShow = 1;
```

And something like this on the front end:

```
<div ng-if="partToShow === 1" ng-include="'/firstpart.html'">
</div>
<div ng-if="partToShow === 2" ng-include="'/secondpart.html'">
</div>
```

This will show firstPart at the beginning.

Change `$scope.partToShow` to `2` to show only secondPart.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to use a pre-processor to substitute the HTML (and typescript) files into a main one. I believe the CLI supports launching an arbitrary pre-processor. Something like this:

mainfile.ts:

```
// {Include: my_sub_file.ts}
// {Include: my_other_file.ts}
// {Include: another_sub_file.ts}
```

mainfile.html:

```
<!-- Include: my_sub_file.ts -->
<!-- Include: my_other_file.ts -->
<!-- Include: another_sub_file.ts -->
```

When add a program or script that just substitutes the values for the entire file contents of other file. Angular will never know it happened, and you can stay more organized. You may be able to use a script to do it quickly, like Python or another nodejs script.

Just a note on auto-rebuilds, because Angular doesn't know that you're doing this, it will not know when you make a change to one of the files. So, whatever solution you use to do the substitutions, needs to monitor the source files for changes.